# The type or namespace name 'Mvc' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?) Kentico

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, content-management-system, kentico

i newly installed Kentico cms in IIS server and when i'm trying to access the localhost web it's give me this error.

[image]

i also allowed ASP.NET 4 in IIS server and still i getting this error
what did i missed here?any help please?

Comment: try cleaning and rebuilding your application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you're missing System.Web.Mvc.dll in bin folder

Answer (score 1):

Go to Nuget Package Manager, then browse and install `System.Web.Mvc` . If it is already installed then try changing its `version`.